# Highcharts, series with data of different size

Tags: highcharts, highcharts-ng

I'm currently working on building a chart in highcharts, where I plot in data by week and month. This means that for every month, there will be 4.3 week-plots. My question is, is there a way to make the by-month data have a similar length as the week (aka, same starting point, and same ending point) instead of the by-month stopping abrubtly after 3-4 datapoints while the by-week stops after 15 or so?

Currently it looks like this:
[image: chart]

This is for daily / weekly, but will be changed to weekly/monthly. Same principle applies. :)

Thanks!

Comment: Managed to figure it out based on http://www.highcharts.com/demo/spline-irregular-time

Comment: Since others may come to this question with a similar situation, please consider answering your own question with your updated code and how you solved your problem. Others will appreciate you for your efforts!

Comment: Fair point, will add an answer in later today! :)

Answer (score 0):

So my goal here was to get the average per-week data listed along with the daily data. While I struggled for a fairly long time, the solution was rather simple.

In chart options, I needed to use datetime:

```
xAxis: {
          type: 'datetime',
          dateTimeLabelFormats: {
            month: '%e. %b',
            year: '%b'
          }
        }
```

After this was in place, I had to format my dates (was mysql-formatted, so YYYY-MM-DD / YYYY-WW). My biggest hurdle here was that the data was 
1) Dynamic from an API endpoint
2) Differing data points (week vs days)

As I could control the API endpoint, I could perform the changes to the dates there to avoid the performance loss on client side. The data needs to be in timestamp w/ ms, and to do this I used momentjs. Example below is for weeks:

```
let d = moment(i.date, 'YYYY-WW').format('YYYY-MM-DD')
let dateFormat = new Date(d);
let date = moment(d).day(parseInt(goToDay)).format('YYYY-MM-DD').split('-')
let utcDate = Date.UTC(parseInt(date[0]), parseInt(date[1]) - 1, parseInt(date[2]))
```

Days were easier:

```
  let date = i.date.split('-');
  let utcDate = Date.UTC(date[0], date[1] - 1, date[2])
```

After this, it was only a matter of sending the data back to the client, and looping over it like so (note I'm using angular, procedure for highcharts w/o angular would be slightly different):

```
$scope.ChartConfig.series = [];
$scope.ChartConfig.series.push({
  name: 'Daily',
  title: 'Daily',
  data: data.daily.data
})
$scope.ChartConfig.series.push({
  name: 'Weekly',
  title: 'Weekly',
  data: data.weekly.data
});
```

This renders the charts perfectly, and just the way I want it to:
[image: justthewayIwantit]